# Using pyinstaller not creating .exe when entered into PyCharm's Python Console

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.8

I am looking into create a simple .exe via pyinstaller.
I keep getting an error. Why is this not working?

Below is the error and what command I am typing.

```
File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\codeop.py", line 118, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<input>", line 1
    pyinstaller --onefile gui.py
                          ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It seems like the error mark in PyCharm community edition is showing a red error in the space after `--onefile` and `gui.py`.

I also attached a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with Python 3.8?

Comment: `pyinstaller --onefile gui.py` is not a Python command that you can enter inside *Python Console*. Maybe try *Terminal* instead.

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for the advice I got it working!

Answer (score 0):

## Use terminal, not python console

Python console is a python interactive interpreter meant to run python code like:

```py
>>> 1 + 4
5
>>> import operator
>>> operator.add(1, 4)
5
```

pyinstaller is a CLI package, meaning that you need to run this command line in a terminal. It's not something meant to be executed in a python file or interactive interpreter.

```bash
$ pyinstaller --onefile gui.py
```

See an example here: [Command Line Scripts](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) about `funniest-joke` package.